# Ruby: NoMethodError on call to display method

Tags: ruby

Greeting, I just started learning Ruby a few weeks with this noob book titled Computer Science Programming Basics in Ruby. I've practiced the exercises in each chapter, haven't had too many error, but I keep getting this error in a class I wrote up for the tic-tac-toe game in the last chapter. Here is the board.rb class file I made:

```
class Board
  BOARD_MAX_INDEX = 2
  EMPTY_POS = ' '

  def initialize(current_player)
    @current_player = current_player
    @board = Array.new(BOARD_MAX_INDEX + 1) {
      Array.new(BOARD_MAX_INDEX + 1) { EMPTY_POS }
    }
  end
end

def display
  puts "+------+"
  for row in 0..BOARD_MAX_INDEX
    print "| "
    for col in 0..BOARD_MAX_INDEX
      s = @board[row][col]
      if s == EMPTY_POS
        print col + (row * 3) + 1
      else
        print s
      end
      print " | "
    end
    puts "\n+------+"
  end
end
```

The class runs fine, but this is the error message in irb when I attempt to access 
the display method call:

```
irb(main):004:0> require '/home/nick/board.rb'
=> true
irb(main):005:0> puts "Starting tic-tac-toe..."
Starting tic-tac-toe...
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> players = ['X', 'O']
=> ["X", "O"]
irb(main):007:0> current_player = players[rand(2)]
=> "O"
irb(main):008:0> b = Board.new(current_player)
=> #<Board:0x00000001c64868 @current_player="O", @board=[[" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", "  "], [" ", " ", " "]]>
irb(main):009:0> b.display()
NoMethodError: private method `display' called for #<Board:0x00000001c64868>
from (irb):9
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Why am I getting this error, what do I have to do to get it to display the board?

Comment: I cleaned up the indentation for you. Hopefully that makes it obvious why you're getting an error.

Comment: Your `display` method is outside of the `Board` class.

Comment: The problem is that you ended the class definition too soon.  Move `end` to the line after the definition of the method `display`.

Comment: Because `display` does not respond to an instance of the class `Board`; i.e., `display` is not an instance method of `Board`.

Comment: I already have a few end statements at the end of the class file, can you show me an example of where I should put this end statement in the display definition.

Comment: @nickshoe, your code happens to respond to `#display` only by chance. You define it not on `Board` class, but directly in `main`, which makes it a private method of `Object` class, from which everyone inherits.

Comment: There is no main method definition shown in the book, so can you guys please show me how to define this display method in the target class the correct way?

Comment: In the book it's defined in the Board class. If I'm supposed to define it directly in main, can someone show me how that should look as opposed to the way I'm doing it, please?

Comment: no you're not supposed to define it in main. That's what your code is doing, though. Compare the code here with the code in the book.

Comment: I wrote the code exactly as shown in the book, what else am I supposed to do?

Comment: Perhaps if you guys read last chapter 12 on tic-tac-toe in this link, you'll see that my code is indistinguishably identical to my code: http://www.pdfiles.com/pdf/files/English/Desktop_Apps_Programming/Computer_Science_Programming_Basics_In_Ruby.pdf                     Can somebody please just look at this code and show me how my code should be written differently

Answer (score 3):

You should put the definition of the `display` method inside the class:

```
end # of class

def display
...
end
```

Should be:

```
  def display
  ...
  end

end # of class
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is it. He didn't define the method on the target class at all.